# Terraform not respecting ssh config for git

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

My terraform module is in a private bitbucket repo accessed via an ssh key.

I don't know what git command terraform runs or how to change auth, but it seems to be using a different ssh config.

this is my `.tf` file:

```
module "sdfsdfs" {
  source = "git::ssh://bitbucket.org/mycomp/my-module-root//submodule"
}
```

I'm running this in a jenkins pipeline and I am editing the ssh config to use a specific key. I have proven this works:

```
sshagent (credentials: ['my-ssh-key']) {
    bat 'git clone git@bitbucket.org:mycomp/my-module.git'
}
```

The ssh config is modified correctly and uses my key store in jenkins.

I don't know what terraform is actually running to pull from git repo but it's not respecting the ssh config:

```
sshagent (credentials: ['my-ssh-key']) {
    bat 'terraform init'
}
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe exited with 128: Cloning into 
'.terraform\modules\c760b746e09bd59ba86aae13dc9e9959'...

Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What is terraform doing or failing to do here? I want to configure this for this session only, so setting a global ssh config for my jenkins server is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is partly a bitbucket limitation, partly me not reading [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html) thoroughly.

The bitbucket api seems to not support ssh or something because, terraform docs only have examples https with bitbucket.

Treating this like a generic git repo works:

```
  source = "git::ssh://git@bitbucket.org/mycomp/myrepo.git//my-sub-module"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is really old but I might help other people who might encounter this problem.
What helped me out in Windows was setting the environment variable GIT_SSH_COMMAND to the path of the ssh.exe.
In cmd, run:

```
setx GIT_SSH_COMMAND C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe
```